# Can nginx log the response to database?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a nginx/uwsgi/django server running a main django app and a secondary for emergency when nginx it timeout. I am logging the response to database in the django app.

The problem comes when the timeout trigger the emergency app after the main log the response. The emergency app is runes rarely but I end up with some duplicates entries.

Although I can ignore the main app entries when the secondary ones exist, I prefer to avoid this.

Is there a way to log the responses from nginx trough a logging tool or script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [syslog output](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html) and chain this to something like [logstash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/) that could then push the content to a nosql database like elasticsearch, redis, mongodb among many others.